# Violación de segmento (`core' generado)

Tags: c

Tengo este código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "matmul.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int i;   
   double start1,start2,start3,end1,end2,end3,t1,t2,t3;
   double* matriza=NULL;
   double* matrizb=NULL;
   double* matrizc=NULL;

   printf("\nMatrices Cuadradas\n");
   for(i=100;i<=1000;i+=100){
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    matriza=(double*)malloc(i*i*sizeof(double));
    cargar_matriz_random(matriza, i, i);
    matrizb=(double*)malloc(i*i*sizeof(double)); 
    cargar_matriz_random(matrizb, i, i);    
    matrizc=(double*)malloc(i*i*sizeof(double));
    cargar_matriz_c(matrizc, i, i);

    start1 = omp_get_wtime();
    matmul_seq(matriza, matrizb, matrizc, i, i, i);
    end1 = omp_get_wtime();

    start2 = omp_get_wtime();
    matmul_o(matriza, matrizb, matrizc, i, i, i);
    end2 = omp_get_wtime();

    start3 = omp_get_wtime();
    matmul_i(matriza, matrizb, matrizc, i, i, i);   
    end3 = omp_get_wtime();

    free(matriza);
    free(matrizb);
    free(matrizc);

    t1=end1-start1;
    t2=end2-start2;
    t3=end3-start3;
    printf("n   t de matmul_seq   t de matmul_o   t de matmul_i\n");
    printf("%d   %lf        %lf           %lf\n",i,t1,t2,t3);
}


return 0;
}
```

Resulta ser que cuando lo ejecuto, en consola aparece el error:
Violación de segmento (`core' generado). Lo ejecuto en otra máquina, y funciona.

Aclaro que las llamadas a malloc() y a free() están bien ubicadas, y las cargas de las matrices se hacen correctamente. También hay que decir que las funciones "matmul..." funcionan correctamente también. Otra cosa que hay que decir es que estas funciones (menos "matmul_seq") están paralelizadas con la directiva for de OpenMP.

Ya sé lo que significa este error, pero todavía no sé como resolverlo.

Comment: Perfecto. Pues si todas las funciones que no muestras están bien, y todos tus `malloc( )` y `free( )` son correctos ... está claro que el problema es la máquina en si. ¿ O será que **es posible** que alguna de tus funciones no esté tan bien ?

Comment: añado a lo que dice @Trauma, ¿como verificas que es correcto? si afirmas algo debes ser capaz de dar pruebas.

Comment: O presentas un ejempló mínimo y **completo** que reproduzca el problema o me temo que vas a obtener el silencio por respuesta ya que con la información que presentas es imposible darte una respuesta.